# hive check comma separated String contains a string

Tags: string, hive

I have a column in hive table `list_ids` which is a list of ids stored as comma separated string.

how can I write a query for this column to check if it stores a particular id

Example:

```
 list_ids = "abc,cde,efg"
```

I want to something like

```
 select * from table_name where list_ids contains cde;
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use Hive standard functions `split` and `array_contains`

`split(string str, string pat)` returns `array<string>` by splitting str around pat (regular expression)

`array_contains(array<T>, value)` returns `true` if array contains value

**`select * from table_name where array_contains(split(list_ids,','),'cde')`**

Comment: Is there a away to do multiple values? i.e. array_contains(split(list_ids,','), 'cde|abc|xyz')

Comment: @blueskin First split the array and then do as many contains as you wish: `from (select split(list_ids,',') as ids_array from table_name) where array_contains(ids_array, 'abc') or array_contains(ids_array, 'xyz');`

Answer (score 23):

Hive supports `LIKE` operator. You can do it easily by using:

`select * from table_name where list_ids like '%cde%';`

Check out this language manual for more info:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF

Comment: just better to write `'%,cde,%'` so ids like `'cdee'` wont return

Comment: @dimamah Unfortunately, '%,abc,%' won't match the example in the OP, because the first item in the list won't have a comma in front. Similarly, the last item won't have a comma behind it.

Comment: Thats right. so we can do : `select * from table_name where concat(',',list_ids,',') like '%,cde,%';`

Answer (score 0):

Use Hive function **explode** you can achieve this.

**Example**

> select  * 
>  from table_name
>  LATERAL VIEW explode(list_ids)
>   exploded_table as list_id_tbl
>  where list_ids='cde'